# Unable to create partition on S3 using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, partitioning, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

I would like to use this new functionality: overwrite specific partition without delete all data in s3

I used the new flag (`spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode="dynamic"`) and test it locally from my IDE and it worked (I was able to overwrite specific partition in s3) but when I deployed it to hdp 2.6.5 with spark 2.3.0 same code didn't create the s3 folders as expected , folder didn't create at all , only temp folder has been created

My code :

```
df.write
.mode(SaveMode.Overwtite)
.partitionBy("day","hour")
.option("compression", "gzip")
.parquet(s3Path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried spark version **2.4**? I have worked with this version and both **EMR** and **Glue** it has worked well, to use the "dynamic" in **version 2.4** just use the code:

```
dataset.write.mode("overwrite")
.option("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
.partitionBy("dt")
.parquet("s3://bucket/output")
```

AWS documentation specifies Spark **version 2.3.2** to use `spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode="dynamic"`.

Reference click [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-committer-reqs.html).